# Como simular um SSL em localhost ASP.NET?

Tags: c#

Como simular um certificado SSL no `localhost`, utilizo Visual Studio 2017, rodando ASP.NET MVC5. Preciso disso pois estou rodando a [API da Cielo](https://developercielo.github.io/manual/cielo-ecommerce) que só aceita requisições via SSL.

Edit: Se eu altero a propriedade `SSL Enabled` para `true` quando eu rodo o projeto e abro a URL `https://localhost:54346/` eu recebo a seguinte página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só queria saber porque negativaram... mas ok, vamos esperar uma resposta ou uma critica sobre a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Abra o `Solution Explorer` e selecione o projeto web
2. Aperte a tecla `F4`.
3. Altere a propriedade `SSL Enabled` para `true`.
   Será criado uma URL na propriedade `SSL URL` que será a `URL` para uso.

**Obs.:** Ao iniciar o Debug, a url acessada ainda será o mostrado na propriedade `URL`. Ignore isso e acesse a `URL` com `HTTPS`.

Caso queira deixar o acesso `HTTPS` como padrão ao iniciar o Debug, faça o seguinte:

1. Na `Solution Explorer`, clique com o botão direito no projeto web e clique em `Properties`;
2. Clique na guia `Web`;
3. Altere a propriedade `Project Url` para o endereço `HTTPS` visto na primeira explicação;
4. Clique em `Create Virtual Directory`.

Pronto! Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Roberto, eu fiz isso mas não to conseguindo rodar o projeto, existe mais alguma configuração a ser feita? da uma olhada no edit do post

Comment: Leonardo, não basta colocar apenas o https:// na url. Tem que colocar a URL com outra porta, conforme pode ver na propriedade `SSL URL`.

Comment: Roberto , continua a mesma página de erro.

Comment: Fiz um exemplo que pode ser baixado no link https://ufile.io/lzz9r     Ao iniciar o debug, pode ser acessado pela URL `http://localhost:4306/` e `https://localhost:44310/`    Veja ae se funciona.